# firebase data not ordering correctly with angularfire2

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

I am trying to create an app to help me learn ionic, firebase, angular, and all that stuff and I can't seem to get the data to properly order when coming from the database. I have an ionic app that has a "posts" provider that gets the "posts" from the database. It is supposed to order by the dateCreated, but it isn't. 
Here is the simple stripped down version of my code...

home.ts

```
import { PostsProvider } from '../../providers/posts/posts';
...

@Component({...})
export class HomePage {
  posts: any;

  constructor(public postsService: PostsProvider) {
    this.posts = this.postsService.getPosts();
  }
}
```

posts.ts

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, FireListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
...

@Injectable
export class PostsProvider {

  constructor(public afPosts: AngularFireDatabase) {
  }

  getPosts() {
    return this.afPosts.list('/posts', {query: {orderByChild: 'dateCreated', limitToLast: 20}});
  }
}
```

then in my home.html file I have...

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-card *ngFor="let post of posts | async">
    <img src="{{post.image}}">
    <ion-card-content>
      <p>{{post.createdOn}}</p>
      <p>{{post.content}}</p>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

My database is very simple, and has the appropriate rules in place for ordering on. Here is a sample of the data in the database...

```
{
"posts" : {
    "-KpGyBqzVKBhLmz0Ydo-" : {
      "author_id" : "mScPMapCgFdiA220zD3eYHoszF43",
      "comments" : [ {
        "author_id" : "fFlYs8NHVegGkI3r4regmxRtFaG3",
        "content" : "Hopefully a new comment shows up on this post",
        "dateCreated" : 1498223724293
      }, {
        "author_id" : "fFlYs8NHVegGkI3r4regmxRtFaG3",
        "content" : "A new Comment maybe?",
        "dateCreated" : 1497130709242
      }, {
        "author_id" : "fFlYs8NHVegGkI3r4regmxRtFaG3",
        "content" : "Another ones",
        "dateCreated" : 1498103266757
      } ],
      "content" : "Sweet crap I hope this works",
      "dateCreated" : 1494841863173,
      "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "postedAgo" : "1S",
      "title" : "First Post"
    }
}
```

And then my rules are as follows...

```
{
  "rules": {
    "posts": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null",
        ".indexOn": "dateCreated"
    }  
  }
}
```

the dateCreated is just a "new Date().getTime()" that way it is easy to order from since it is just an integer. The problem is, for whatever reason the database is ordering by "author_id" and then by "dateCreated". All of my posts that are shown on the page will be in chronological order, but grouped by author_id, so I will see everything one person posted in order, then everything someone else posted in order, instead of it just coming back ordered by the dateCreated field.

Can anyone see any reason why this would not be ordering them right? It is driving me insane, all the docs say add the .indexOn in the rules, then just add the orderByChild when querying the data. I have also tried using it like so...

```
this.afPosts.ref('/posts').orderByChild('dateCreated').limitToLast(20).subscribe(data => { ... });
```

But I get the same output. It is ordered by user and then ordered by date.Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: please try to change to ".indexOn": ["comments/dateCreated"]

Comment: @mohamadrabee but, I need them sorted by post date, not comment date. Wouldn't that sort by comment date? Or do you just want to see if that will do what it;s supposed to do?

Comment: I did not notice that post and comments have children with the same key name, so please try to change dateCreated to postDateCreated

Comment: @mohamadrabee do you know of an easy way to do that? I have over 100 posts in my test database and editing each one manually will take a while. Is there some quick batch thing I can do to rename all of them? I definitely see your thought process and I like it, it sounds legit, just hoping I don't have to manually go through every post in my database and change the key name.

Comment: In firebase console you have the option to export data as json, so export it, edite the json file and import it to firebase back